# Startup bash script to reload network if network interfaces are down

Tags: bash, shell, networking, openwrt

I have several boards that frequently need to be power cycled. About ten percent of the time, the network interfaces fail to come up (ifconfig shows nothing, r8169 driver fails to load, etc.). I am trying to figure out the root cause but in the meantime need a quick fix. I wrote a quick bash script that runs on startup to detect if the interfaces are down by pinging the local interface, then reloads the network if necessary.

Relevant code section:

```
echo 'fixnet running' > $NV_LOG

if ping -c 1 127.0.0.1; then
    echo "Network ok." >> $NV_LOG
else
    echo "$ERR Network down, starting up" >> $NV_LOG
    /etc/init.d/network restart
fi
```

If I manually run this script (./testNet.sh), it works as expected. However, if the script is run at startup, it seems to fail during the ping test command ('fixnet running' is output to $NV_LOG, but nothing else). This occurs when the networking interfaces are down - if the network started up fine this startup script also works properly. I am new to bash scripting, and don't know where to proceed from here.

Edit: It actually appears that when the board fails, the script does not execute at all. Thanks for the solutions, but the problem lies somewhere else. I'll close the question.

Comment: Provide with the full path to the `ping` binary. (ie. `/bin/ping -c 1 127.0.0.1`)

Comment: I disagree with the statement i.e. if "IF" statement will fail it's not doing anything, then it'll for sure, echo $ERR Network down, staring up line in the same log file... it seems like, ping command never returned any result to IF statement thus, no output in the log other than just "fixnet running"

Answer (score 2):

You could guess the `ping` command is *stuck* for some reason. Maybe at route resolution?
BTW, you ping *127.0.0.1* which is *localhost*. As far as I can tell, this is filtered at kernel level to not even reach the network stack. Are you sure this could really tell if your network interface is up?

Anyway, to test if an interface is *UP* or *DOWN* you might rely on the `ip` command instead. It does not send packed over the network, but merely check the interface status:

Here, to check if my *eth0* interface is up or down:

```
if ip addr show eth0 | grep 'state UP'; then
    echo "Network ok."
else
    echo "$ERR Network down, starting up"
    /etc/init.d/network restart
fi 2>&1 >> $NV_LOG
```

Please note I redirect the whole *if statement* to the log file. This allow to capture both the output of the `ip` command, your messages, and output or `/etc/init.d/network restart`.

Comment: Very useful script!